# Can I create multiple Github repos with one large folder with many files in it?

Tags: git, github

So I have one large coursework folder with 30+ files in it, where 3 or 4 files represents a different project that I built for that course. I want to organize these files with their separate repos on GitHub. Most likely I will not be changing these files in the future. I just want to put these files on Github with separate repos.

I started with making a new repo on Github and then `git remote add origin [link to my 1st repo]`

This approach worked for the very first repo but now it also adding the files in my first repo along with new files in the second repo, which I don't want.

To get around this issue, then I tried changing the remote link using `git remote set-url origin [link to my 2nd repo]`

But this didn't work either. Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

to share files between two repositories you can put them in a third repository that you import as submodule. A submodule is basically a reference to another revision on another repository saved into your working tree, that will be checked out as a folder.

It is a pretty extensive argument though, have a look at documentation for git-submodule to understand how to set it up.

Changing remote is something that affect only your local copy, and makes it refer to another repository. It works if your two repositories are basically copies of each other.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, I don't want to share files between repos. I want to create SEPARATE repos on Github with the files that I have on my machine in a single coursework folder.

Comment: so you just want 2 copies of the same repository on github?

Comment: No, I think you are misunderstanding the question. I have a folder called coursework on my machine with many files like: file 1, file 2, file 3, file 4, file 5, and file 6. On Github, I want to create repo1 with file 1, file 2 and file 3. Also, I want to create repo 2 with files file 4, file 5 and file 6. If that make sense.

Comment: your local copy is a repository, not a collection of files. So in the local repository you have all 6 files. You can either sync your local repository with remote repo1 or remote repo2, the one you sync with will have all the files. You can use submodules to have part of a repository be a reference to another repository, but submodules have folder granularity so your files 123 would be in a different folder than 456.

Comment: (note that using submodules is not much different than having your files into two repositories in the local disk)

Comment: I guess I am just gonna use the Github web version for this task. Thanks though!